# how to validate the UI error with no error message in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my page contains ui fields which has the typical validations on it. but the thing is, instead of displaying a message explicitly, it highlights the field border with red color. might be some css changes might happen behind based on the validations. while in scripting, how can i validate/assert the filed shows me a validation error here. lets say 'Email' field is a mandatory. When i save the form with empty value, it highlights the Email filed with Red color border. Any help here on how to validate.

When it has value the html looks like,

```
<input aria-label="email" aria-atomic="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-readonly="false" autocomplete="off" class="Input__field Input__field--with-trailing-icon" data-has-errors="false" id="email" inputmode="email" maxlength="100" name="email" novalidate="" placeholder="" required="" tabindex="-1" type="email" value="test@gmail.com">
```

When it is empty,

```
<input aria-label="email" aria-atomic="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-invalid="true" aria-readonly="false" autocomplete="off" class="Input__field Input__field--empty-warning Input__field--with-trailing-icon" data-has-errors="true" id="email" inputmode="email" maxlength="100" name="email" novalidate="" placeholder="" required="" tabindex="-1" type="email" value="">
```

(as i am into client server, i cannot post a screen-print of the UI filed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When highlighted the element has class name `Input__field--empty-warning` also `data-has-errors="true"`.
So you can pass that element to method like this:

```
public void validateClassInElement(WebElement element, String className){
    String classes = element.getAttribute("class");
    Assert.assertTrue(classes.contains(className));
}
```

Or

```
public void validateAttributeValueInElement(WebElement element, String att, String expectedValue){
    String actualValue = element.getAttribute(att);
    Assert.assertTrue(actualValue.contains(expectedValue));
}
```

So it can be:

```
WebElement emailInput = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"));
validateClassInElement(emailInput,"Input__field--empty-warning");
```

Alternatively this can be done with `WebDriverWait` `ExpectedConditions`

```
boolean status = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"), "class", "Input__field--empty-warning"));
```

or

```
boolean status = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"), "data-has-errors", "true"));
```

Comment: Yes, i did the same way and it works well. Thanks for the idea. `String expErrorAttribute = "Input__field--empty-warning";
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(inputEmail, "class", expErrorAttribute));
        return inputEmail.getAttribute("class").contains(expErrorAttribute);`